# How do you set the focus onto a control with Alt-D?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I would like to set the focus onto a control when the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. However, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> sets the focus on the first item in the menustrip after setting the focus in the keydown event handler.

Setting the form KeyPreview to True and e.Handled to true when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed has no effect.

D is an arbitrary key for this example -- it happens on all alpha keys.

I'm using vb.net 2008.

Sample code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

If e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
  Button1.Focus()
  e.Handled = True
End If

End Sub
```

Sample form, after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Focus was on Button2 before pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the [`ProcessDialogKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

This code will do:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean

If keyData = (Keys.Alt Or Keys.D) Then
  Call Form1_KeyDown(Nothing, New KeyEventArgs(Keys.Alt Or Keys.D))
  Return True
Else
  Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Alt And keyData = Keys.D Then
        Button1.Focus()
    End If
    Return True 'im not sure about this, I forgot the code
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: This would work, but there are a couple of bugs in here. ProcessDialogKey also works, and might be better.

Comment: well this is the code I use if I want some hotkeys in my app. Haven't had a problem till now. Though I haven't tried two keys simultaneously :P

Comment: "Button1.Focus()" is never executed. "Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)" is never executed. It's still very helpful, hence the upvote -- thanks!

Comment: in my case works with OR instead of AND for evaluating keyData combination. is better the Patrick's solution